# Add Logo and coin name to StellarTerm token

Tags: exchanges

I have created a token on StellarTerm

https://stellarterm.com/#exchange/CUP-GBOHSTY67CQXD5ANUJNMXHA3HCYEOCLOT22XA46A5P3QDOSLKS3BOGIT/XLM-native

How to add a logo and change "unknown" to something branded?

Answer (score 3):

Set a home domain on your token issuer account and that domain should serve stellar.toml file with meta info about tokens you issue.

Docs: https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/stellar-toml.html
Example: https://mobius.network/.well-known/stellar.toml

This alone will make your token appear with a logo and info on most Stellar wallets. If you want your token to appear in markets list on StellarTerm, it should be listed in StellarTerm Directory. You can read about the process and requirements here: https://github.com/irisli/stellarterm/tree/master/directory#how-to-get-listed.